# How can I define a GoLang structure with varying field types

Tags: json, go, data-structures

I'm relatively new to GoLang, and am having trouble with the strict typing system (I'm much more used to weakly typed languages).

In trying to write a Alexa SmartHome skill I need to create the JSON structures defined (e.g) at https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-contactsensor.html

The StateReport Response is where I start to have trouble, in particular with the context.

The example looks like:

```
  "context": {
    "properties": [
      {
        "namespace": "Alexa.ContactSensor",
        "name": "detectionState",
        "value": "NOT_DETECTED",
        "timeOfSample": "2017-02-03T16:20:50.52Z",
        "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
      },
      {
        "namespace": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
        "name": "connectivity",
        "value": {
          "value": "OK"
        },
        "timeOfSample": "2017-02-03T16:20:50.52Z",
        "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

At first glance this looks simple enough:

```
    Context struct {
        Properties []struct {
            Namespace                 string    `json:"namespace"`
            Name                      string    `json:"name"`
            Value                     string    `json:"value"`
            Timeofsample              time.Time `json:"timeOfSample"`
            Uncertaintyinmilliseconds int       `json:"uncertaintyInMilliseconds"`
        } `json:"properties"`
    } `json:"context"`
```

But the "Value" field is where I have the problem.

In the first element of the array we have a simple string

```
        "value": "NOT_DETECTED",
```

but the *second* element is a structure

```
        "value": {
          "value": "OK"
        },
```

(This doesn't seem to be a typo in the docs; it's repeated at https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-endpointhealth.html and elsewhere as well).

And this is where the strict typing of GoLang and my knowledge of the language begins to defeat me.

How can I model this `value` element, since it doesn't seem to have a fixed type?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The quick fix would be to use `interface{}`, and then to handle the value you'd use a type assertion. The proper way to do this would be to declare a custom type that implements the `json.Unmarshaler` interface and the implementation would correctly unmarshal the different input.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks.  That hint helped and I was able to come up with a possible solution.  Something new I learned about Go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint from mkopriva I think I came up with simple proof of concept solution using `interface{}` and anonymous structures

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
        Value interface{} `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
        v1 := Foo{Value: "version1"}
        j1, _ := json.Marshal(v1)
        fmt.Println(string(j1))

        v2 := Foo{Value: struct {
                Value string `json:"value"`
        }{Value: "version2"}}
        j2, _ := json.Marshal(v2)
        fmt.Println(string(j2))
}
```

Running this gives the two ouputs:

```
{"value":"version1"}
{"value":{"value":"version2"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a type like this:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// nullOK is a JSON OK literal
var nullOK = []byte("OK")

type ValueString struct {
    Error string
    Valid bool
}

// UnmarshalJSON implements json.Unmarshaler.
func (s *ValueString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if bytes.Equal(data, nullOK) {
        s.Valid = true
        return nil
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s.Error); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("checking OK: couldn't unmarshal JSON: %w", err)
    }

    s.Valid = false
    return nil
}

// MarshalJSON implements json.Marshaler.
func (s ValueString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if s.Valid {
        return []byte("OK"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(s.Error)
}
```

And use it in your struct:

```golang
...
Value                     ValueString    `json:"value"`
...
```

When value is "OK" your `Value.Valid` will be `true`, else check the `Value.Error` for parsed value.

Comment: Thanks.  This is interesting.  But I think I'll go with the simple `interface{}` approach!